# incompatible types object cannot be converted to t where t is a type variable

Tags: java, types

I'm getting the **Incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to T where T is a type variable: T extends Object declared in class Stack.**
Can you please help, I don't know why it is so, method pop() and getData() are of the same type T...
Here is the shortened code.

```
public class Stack<T> {
    Node head;

    public T pop() {
         return head.getData();    //the error is on this line
    }

    private class Node <T> {
        private final T data;
        private Node next;

        private Node(T data, Node next) {
            this.data=data;
            this.next=next;
        }

        private T getData() {
            return data;
        } 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It must be `Node<T> head`. You forgot to add the type parameter.

Comment: Thank you, I knew it must be something trivial :)

Comment: @FiloménaPetržlénová - `rgetmann` made a sensible answer too. The Node class should be static "private static class Node", otherwise each Stack object will have a separate Node object which is not needed.

Comment: Actually I meant to say that when the Node class is instantiated, it will have a reference to the Stack object, which is not needed.

Answer (score 3):

You've declared an inner class `Node` that defines its own type parameter `T` (it's different than `Stack`'s `T`).  However, you are using a raw `Node` when you declare `head`.  Type erasure applies, and calling `getData()` on a raw `Node` returns an `Object`.

Remove the type parameter `T` on `Node`.  Because it's not `static`, the `Stack`'s class's `T` type parameter is in scope for `Node`.  `Node` can simply use `Stack`'s `T` type parameter.

```
private class Node  {
```

Comment: Good answer, I also think Node class should be static.